# How to know if a process is going to get "Permission denied"

Tags: bash

```
Me@ubuntu:~$ cat /proc/10/syscall
cat: /proc/10/syscall: Permission denied
```

I want to know ahead of time if I will have permission for access to `syscall`.

I tried to do it with this:

```
FILE=/proc/$N/syscall
    if [ -r $FILE ]; then
        cat /proc/$N/syscall
    else
        echo "can't read"
    fi
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Why do you write that it's not working? What version of bash do you use?